# Creating zip with powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

I would like to use powershell to make multiple zip files. Example: I have a folder with multiple files and I want them zipped in packages of 4.

Can someone tell me if it's possible, and if yes, how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: "I want them zipped in packages of 4" - are they supposed to be grouped together based on something specific, or just batches of any 4 files in the folder? Is the number of files in the folder always a multiple of 4?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't very specific. I would like them to be grouped on filename. Something like this: hello1.txt
hello2.txt
hello3.txt
hello4.txt
Etc.
And then 1 to 4 should be together and 5 to 8 etc.

Comment: And all the file names share a common prefix (eg. they're all named like `hello{number}.txt`)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could group the files into chunks, which can be sorted beforehand by using the common number prefix in `hello{number}.txt`.

```
$counter = 0

$groups = Get-ChildItem -Path .\helloFolder |
    Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = { [int][System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name).TrimStart("hello") } } |
        Group-Object -Property { [System.Math]::Floor($Script:counter++ / 4) }
```

To sort correctly we'll need to extract the number prefix from the filename. We can use [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=net-5.0) to get the filename, then strip the `hello` from the beginning of the string using [`System.String.TrimStart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-5.0#System_String_TrimStart_System_Char___). We can then cast this to `[int]` and use it as the sorting property for [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.1). This will ensure the files are ordered by prefix, since files like `hello10.txt` will naturally be sorted before `hello3.txt` if you just sort by filename.

To group the files, we can divide the counter by `4`, then round down using [`System.Math.Floor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.floor?view=net-5.0). We can then use property with [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1).

To explain this in more detail, if we had 8 files, this would do the following groupings:

```
# Group 1
hello1.txt -> floor(0 / 4) = 0
hello2.txt -> floor(1 / 4) = 0
hello3.txt -> floor(2 / 4) = 0
hello4.txt -> floor(3 / 4) = 0

# Group 2
hello5.txt -> floor(4 / 4) = 1
hello6.txt -> floor(5 / 4) = 1
hello7.txt -> floor(6 / 4) = 1
hello8.txt -> floor(7 / 4) = 1
```

Which can also handle cases where there are leftover chunks with a size less than 4, since they will be added to the next available group.

We can then archive the chunked files into `zipfile{number}.zip` using [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.1), which can accept an array of paths `[-Path] <string[]>` from `$group.Group.FullName`.

```
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Compress-Archive -Path $group.Group.FullName -DestinationPath "zipfile$([int]$group.Name + 1).zip"
}
```

You can also combine all the above into one pipeline if you prefer to do that:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\helloFolder |
    Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = { [int][System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name).TrimStart("hello") } } |
        Group-Object -Property { [System.Math]::Floor($Script:counter++ / 4) } |
            ForEach-Object {
                Compress-Archive -Path $group.Group.FullName -DestinationPath "zipfile$([int]$group.Name + 1).zip"
            }
```